# Using NSThread to create game loop

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, nsthread

I'm trying to create game loop which runs in separate thread. I decided to use `NSThread` object instead of `CADisplayLink` and `NSTimer`.
To test if `OpenGLES` is working correctly I'm clearing the screen by solid color.
The problem here is that all is working fine with no loops, single render call from `initWithFrame`. But when I put my render code inside game loop, or just simply create new thread and call render code from new thread there is nothing happens in the screen.
Here is my `initWithFrame` function which is called from `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    [self setupLayer];
    [self setupContext];
    [self setScaleFactor];      
    [self initGame];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(render) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
return self;
}
```

And this is render function:

```
- (void)render
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

If I put render call instead of creating thread inside `initWithFrame`, all works fine. But with current implementation I get black screen, despite render function is called.
I also tried using

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render) object:nil];
[thread start];
```

It does not make pink screen to appear either.
Appreciate any advices how can I use threads to get OpenGl ES rendered to the screen.

Comment: OpenGL is far from thread-safe.  You must draw into the context on the same thread in which it was created.

Comment: Thank you for your Comment.
Can I create the context in separate thread and draw into it there?

Comment: That is the way to do it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@interface GameObject
{
  BOOL hasStoppedRendering;
}

@end

@implementation GameObject

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self)
   {
    [self setupLayer];
    [self setupContext];
    [self setScaleFactor];      
    [self initGame];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(render) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
   }
  return self;
}

- (void)render
{
    while(!hasStoppedRendering)
    {
      /*BEGIN RENDERING CODE*/
          glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0);
          glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      /*END RENDERING CODE*/

     [self performSelector:@selector(presentRenderBuffer) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; 
    }

}

- (void)presentRenderBuffer
{
  [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}


@end
```

Comment: As @borrrden said, context object must be used in the same thread where it was created. Otherwise render code would not work.
Now I get it working with creating and using context in the same thread, but I still have to solve why I can't use loop inside thread function. I have terrible performance now, 1-3fps. Probably it's connected with presenting render buffer.

Answer (score -1):

add [`EaglContext setCurrentContext:eaglobject];`